# Undefined offset 1 in my php code - how to avoid it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an sql query that returns:

```
start_time of the event  |  end time of the event   |   duration of the event
```

In my php code I'm iterating over the results and I'm checking if I can insert another event between existing ones - basically I'm checking if the difference in time between the end of one event and start of previous event is longer than duration of the previous event - if yes then I'm saving its end date as a start date for a freshly created event.

I created a php query that happens right after I do the sql SELECT query:

```
if($q3->rowCount()>0)
{
    $check3 = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($check3 as $row) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }

    $firstRow = $arr[0]; 

        for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            $current_row = $arr[$i];
            $next_row    = $arr[$i+1];

            if (($next_row["begin_date"] - $current_row["end_date"]) >= $duration){
                $found_timestamp_for_new_event = $current_row["end_date"];
                break;
            }

        }

    $last_element = ($arr[count($arr) - 1]['end_date']);    
    if($end_timestamp - $last_element >= $duration){
        $found_timestamp_for_new_event = $last_element;

    }
 }
```

However, when I run it, I'm getting the warning:

```
Notice Undefined offset: 1 in ...
```

and the warning is in line `$next_row    = $arr[$i+1];`.
I think it happens because in some cases the query returns no more events and therefore it doesn't see the `$arr[$i+1]`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error raises when you reach the last element of the array. Check if there actually is another element using an IF statement.

```
if ( $i < count($arr)-1 ) {
    // THERE IS AT LEAST ANOTHER ROW AFTER THIS
    $next_row = $arr[$i+1];
} else {
    // THIS IS THE LAST ROW, DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE
}
```